# Do users have control over specifying dimension for file properties window

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I have developed a desktop app using electron framework (simple HTML and Javascript). I have set some file properties like file description, file name etc.

I want to alter the size this to my need, Is that possible.
Note: I am running this in windows machine but later on I might run the same application

In the pictures they are properties windows, that show for two different applications, I want to have same dimension how to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What code are you using to open these windows? Have you checked the electron documentation for that call?

Comment: I don't these windows are controlled by Electron

Comment: Yeah these windows are not controlled by electron, right clean on icon you can see this window

Comment: Let me know If we have control over altering this window